# How to list manually installed packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, aptitude

I'd like to get a list of packages installed manually by `apt` or `aptitude` and be able to find out whether a `foobar` package was installed manually or automatically.

How can we do that from the command line?

Comment: See [this answer on unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3624) for a solution that filters out stock packages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to tell what packages I've installed that aren't in the vanilla install?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/365/is-it-possible-to-tell-what-packages-ive-installed-that-arent-in-the-vanilla-i)

Comment: Really good solution that excludes packages installed by default: [Ubuntu list explicitly installed packages](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3624/43920)

Comment: _"package was installed manually or automatically"_ How about manually or by _dependency_. I just did clean install of Debian for WSL, followed by apt update and custom install of only 5 package _names_: ack, zsh, vim, tree, git. Three of the high-vote solutions below make a list of 112 items.

Answer (score 347, accepted):

You can use either of these two one-liners. Both yield the exact same output on my machine and are more precise than all solutions proposed up until now (July 6, 2014) in this question.

**Using `apt-mark`:**

```
comm -23 <(apt-mark showmanual | sort -u) <(gzip -dc /var/log/installer/initial-status.gz | sed -n 's/^Package: //p' | sort -u)
```

**Using `aptitude`:**

```
comm -23 <(aptitude search '~i !~M' -F '%p' | sed "s/ *$//" | sort -u) <(gzip -dc /var/log/installer/initial-status.gz | sed -n 's/^Package: //p' | sort -u)
```

Very few packages still fall through the cracks, although I suspect these *are* actually installed by the user, either right after the installation through the language localization setup or e.g. through the Totem codec installer. Also, the linux-header versions also seem to accumulate, even though I've only installed the non version-specific metapackage. Examples:

```
libreoffice-help-en-gb
openoffice.org-hyphenation
gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3
linux-headers-3.13.0-29
```

**How does it work:**

1. Get the list of manually installed packages. For aptitude, the additional `sed` strips out remaining whitespace at the end of the line.
2. Get the list of packages installed right after a fresh install.
3. Compare the files, only output the lines in file 1 that are not present in file 2.

**Other possibilities don't work as well:**

- Using the `ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.manifest` file ([here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/releases/trusty/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.manifest) for Ubuntu 14.04) instead of `/var/log/installer/initial-status.gz`. More packages are shown as manually installed even though they are not.
- Using `apt-mark showauto` instead of `/var/log/installer/initial-status.gz`. `apt-mark` for example doesn't include the xserver-xorg package, while the other file does.

I used various other StackExchange posts as references, however none work as well as the above solution:

- [aptitude + manifest](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3624/49168)
- [initial-status.gz + apt-mark showauto](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80520/49168)

Both list more packages than the above solution.

**EDIT: What to do if you've upgraded from a previous release:**

If you've upgraded Ubuntu from one release to the next, you will probably need to adjust this process. In that case, I would check the manifest file of the newer release (see above) in addition to the initial-status.gz file from the current release. You can easily do that by just adding another comparison. Using just the manifest file will not work, as the manifest file unfortunately does not contain everything that the initial_status.gz file does (I checked).

Comment: This didn't work for me because `/var/log/installer/initial-status.gz` is missing. Also I want to know if this is depending on apts marking of `manual` or not?

Comment: Alas there is no manifest for server versions.

Comment: I ran the `showmanual` command (below).  And use `comm` to compare the two(sorted)  lists.  The `showmanual` result gave me 1,840 _more_ unique packages from `apt-mark showmanual` not shown by this method.   NO packages were unique to the output of this `comm`-command.  I think it is more interesting to record that for my PC, **894** packages are listed in Both results.  Not sure why there's such a Vast discrepancy.  Some (many?) packages seem to be release specific.  Others like XOrg, GTK components and `lib*` things could be updates.   _Anyway_ this answer is a very good start.

Comment: I just compared your solutions with `apt-mark showmanual`. It's interesting how many differences are visible. your list has 238 packages while showmanual returns 1717 packages. Of the 2179 installed packages, there are only 223 in both lists, 15 are only in yours (examples: nodejs, lightdm) and 223 are only in showmanual (examples: xserver-xorg, ubuntu-desktop). It feels like your list is more helpful, but without knowing where these differences come from, it's not easy to decide... (but I'm quite sure I installed nginx and lightdm manually...) [sorry will that I just wrote the same ;)]

Comment: Is there a way to get a concise list of what packages ***I*** installed? I expect a list with 30-ish items, but it's full of stuff like 1) things I've never ever even heard of (like `zenity`), 2) Things I've heard of but consider core functionality (like `acpi-support`), 3) stuff that's 100% useless to me (like ten `printer-driver-xxx` while I don't even have a printer) and 4) stuff that's almost surely installed by another app and not by me (like `thunderbird-locale-en`)

Comment: Manifest files can be downloaded from http://releases.ubuntu.com/

Comment: This answer is the best I found until now. However, it (still) misses transient package suggestions (and recommendations). For example, when I `apt install git-review`, only `git-review` gets listed. So far, so good. When I `apt remove git-review`, the package git stays but is not listed. That is because git is a ‘suggests’ in the package libdpkg-perl (see /var/lib/dpkg/status). The same happens for if a package was installed with `apt install --no-install recommends` and later another package installs that recommendation, then it stays but gets not listed. No idea how to catch those.

Comment: I originally installed an older version of Ubuntu and now I'm running 20.04, so I downloaded the manifest from http://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.manifest and then I ran `comm -23 <(apt-mark showmanual | sort -u) <(cat ~/Desktop/ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.manifest | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u)`. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexanderTraud: not sure if you _want_ to catch those. `git-review` was the package you installed manually.  `git` was not, be it a suggestion or a dependency.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus: most likely they were installed by your Desktop Environment, on your behalf, when you confirmed a request to _"install support for..."_ (specially `*-locale-*` when fiddling with the Language support GUI). They can't be marked as auto or `apt autoremove` would remove them, so your DE installs them as manual

Comment: Wow, this is golden!!! Might not be perfectly accurate, but I think this is the closest we can get. I've made it an [`apt-list-manual` function in `~/.bash_aliases`](https://github.com/MestreLion/scripts/blob/main/home/bash_aliases#L107-L141), also handling downloaded manifests as suggested by @bmaupin

Comment: @MestreLion when `git-review` is still installed, I do not need to list `git`, yes. However, when I remove `git-review`, I want to know that there are left-over packages, in that case `git`. In this case `git` is still marked installed automatically although it is just a Suggests. There is more than one package which _keeps_ `git` installed. Example use-case: I use an application, do not want to use it anymore and get rid of everything installed for it. Now, one can argue that this is not the initial question. However, such transitions might be not known while the question was phrased.

Comment: Yes, the _intention_ each of us have for this can be different from the OP's, tho I imagine a common scenario is to be able to re-create a system after installing a (fresh) new release. In this scenario, and in yours too, I fail to see _why_ listing `git` among manually installed packages would be useful. If no one else suggests or depends on it, `apt autoremove` can take care of it.

Comment: @AlexanderTraud: if your goal with this command is to "remove all _your_ manual 'intervention', leaving the system 'as-if' it was just installed and updated", then you can `mapfile -t mypackages < <(this answer); sudo apt purge "${mypackages[@]}" && sudo apt autoremove`

Comment: @MestreLion `Installed by another application` ... `Installed by [my] Desktop Environment`. Yep, installed by another application (DE) and not by me (using apt).

Comment: @MestreLion `autoremove` does not take care in my case because git is a Suggests of a totally different, a default installed package. ,Consequently, when anything installs git as side effect, git ‘sticks’ on my system. Consequently, my use-case is about about those packages which are listed at ‘The following NEW packages will be installed’: git-review git git-man liberror-perl. I consider those manual installed. Apt considers only git-review installed manually. Which is fine while installing and having. However, git stays installed and stays marked ‘auto’, even when I remove git-review.

Comment: @AlexanderTraud: But `apt` is doing the right thing: `git-review` is indeed the only package you requested to install, the others were pulled automatically as dependencies/suggestions. To mark `git` as manual, as you consider it, means _nothing_ would be ever marked as automatic, and the whole point of `auto`/`manual`  would be completely moot. `git` only stayed because someone _else_ now requires/suggests it, but it's still an automatically installed package. _You_ never directly requested it.

Comment: And `autoremove` _does_ take care in your case, by removing any "unneeded" packages that were not directly requested by you. `git` is just _not_ unneeded anymore, someone else now requires/suggests it, so `autoremove` should not remove it. It's still `auto` _as it should be_, and "eligible" to autoremove _if and when no one else depends on ti_

Comment: @AlexanderTraud See https://askubuntu.com/questions/351085 for your use-case, it is different from what my answer provides. In the answer above, if you only install "git-review" you do _not_ want "git" to occur in the list of manually installed packages, unless you explicitly type "apt-get install git" at some point. Once you do install "git", apt-get will print "git set to manually installed." and mark it as manual. The main problem this answer solves is that some packages are installed by Ubuntu automatically but marked as manual because of the way they are installed, these are filtered out.

Comment: @jmiserez The question is what is ‘manually’ installed. I have installed git manually because I installed git-review, as a side-effect. That is a fact. Apt marks and calls this ‘automatic’ for various reasons. Now, when I remove git-review, git ‘sticks’ on my system as a side-effect, because it is recommended/suggested by another package. The latter side-effect was not obvious for me. I love your solution, however, it has a side-effect not obvious. Actually, it took quite some time for me to understand why some packages ‘stuck’. And that is because of this transitive relationships.

Comment: @MestreLion the problem is exactly your mentioned ‘not needed anymore’. On a vanilla minimal Ubuntu, install git-review, remove git-review, and git stucks. Not because a **later** installed package ‘needs’ git but because a core package suggest**ed** git. That is hard to understand. And I do not want to remove all suggested packages. I just want to take track of my manually installed packages. In an ideal world, Apt would change the marking of such transitive installations: git lost is automatic, manually installed parent, but is in relation to another package, and mark it manual.

Comment: @AlexanderTraud Your question and personal definition  of manually installed seems to be different from what is answered here. Both MestreLion and I have pointed you towards multiple alternatives that deal with suggested packages. If you need a different answer you should probably look at the other answers or ask a new question.

Answer (score 127):

In newer versions of the package apt, there is also the apt-mark command

```
apt-mark showmanual
```

Comment: Exactly the answer I was searching for.

Comment: This shows way more packages than I have installed manually.

Comment: @Umang You are right. I would say this wasn't like this when I wrote this answer. There is no reason on my system to consider `linux-image-3.11.0-*-generic` etc as manual

Comment: @Umang maybe this will help you http://askubuntu.com/questions/432743/how-are-packages-classified-in-apt-mark-showauto-showmanual, but the answer is not accepted. Fact is, that many packages of a fresh installation are already marked as manual. But there are still some strange things. To stay with my example: `linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic` is manual but the current `linux-image-3.13.0-27-generic` is automatic. It seems that an upgrade of a referencing package (in this case `linux-image-generic`, which changed the dependencies), the manual mark is automatically set

Comment: @DanielAlder some packages of a fresh installation should be marked as manual. If no packages marked as manual, the entire system could be deleted with `apt-get autoremove`. This is definitely not what you want.

Comment: @AntonK that is usually done with the `ubuntu-minimal` and `ubuntu-standard` packages, there's no need for any of their dependencies to be marked as manual

Comment: Wow. It's 2021 and I had to find this post to learn about `apt-mark`.

Answer (score 53):

To get a list of all packages (not installed, installed by user or installed by default, across all PPAs), `apt` employs the following method:

`apt list [option]`

The possible options useful for this are:

`--installed` to display only the packages that are installed on the system (out of some 50,000+)

`--manual-installed` to list the packages that were *explicitly* installed by a command, either directly, or as dependencies.

Alternatively, you could do:

`apt list --installed | grep -F \[installed\]` to get a list of packages that resulted from user commands and their dependencies only, and to get additional information on them such as version and architecture supported (x86, x86_64, amd64, all, etc.)

Comment: Should be the accepted answer, for modern Ubuntues

Comment: This still appears to list packages included in the base installation, which were not explicitly installed by the user running `apt install ...`.

Answer (score 51):

For Ubuntu 16.04, check out the log file `/var/log/apt/history.log`.

For example:

```sh
zgrep 'Commandline: apt' /var/log/apt/history.log /var/log/apt/history.log.*.gz
```

It's not perfect, but it's pretty good at making it clear exactly what I installed by hand.  Put a `-B 1` on the grep to see when it was installed.

Example output

```
Commandline: apt install postgresql-9.5-plv8
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-install-file' sender=':1.85'
Commandline: apt install task
Commandline: apt autoremove
Commandline: apt install atom
Commandline: apt upgrade
Commandline: apt-get install asciinema
Commandline: apt install iperf3
Commandline: apt upgrade
Commandline: apt-get install chromium-browser
Commandline: apt install joe cpanminus build-essential postgresql libdbd-pg-perl libcrypt-openssl-bignum-perl libcrypt-openssl-rsa-perl libio-socket-ssl-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libssl-dev
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.2314'
Commandline: apt install git
Commandline: apt install sqlite
Commandline: apt install whois
Commandline: apt install libdbd-pg-perl
Commandline: apt install perl-doc
Commandline: apt upgrade
```

Not sure if this picks up `aptitude` or not.  It doesn't seem to pick up installs from the Ubuntu Software desktop app.

Comment: you say it's not perfect, but it is indeed beautiful

Comment: This should be updated to be the accepted answer.

Comment: You can parse this to get all install minus all remove/purge command lines: `comm -23 <(zgrep "Commandline: \(apt\|apt-get\) install" /var/log/apt/history.log* | sed -n 's/^Commandline: \(apt\|apt-get\) install //p' | tr " " "\n" | sort -u) <(zgrep "Commandline: \(apt\|apt-get\) \(remove\|purge\)" /var/log/apt/history.log* | sed -n 's/^Comma
ndline: \(apt\|apt-get\) \(remove\|purge\) //p' | tr " " "\n" | sort -u)`

Comment: Note that under default log rotation settings, apt only keeps the last 12 months of history. If you're dealing with a server that's a few years old, this approach can miss packages. You can edit the file `/etc/logrotate.d/apt` to change this retention period.

Answer (score 23):

`apt-mark showauto | grep -iE '^foobar$'` will output "foobar" if the package was installed automatically, nothing otherwise.

`aptitude search '!~M ~i'` will list the packages that were not installed automatically. It's a pity aptitude won't be part of the default install on Ubuntu Desktop starting from 10.10.

Comment: `aptitude search` shows ALL packages not just the ones that are manually installed (I assume that's what the OP wanted)

Comment: @Oli: look into aptitude search patterns; the pattern I'm using there should do exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: I *ran* it. It shows a whole load of packages that aren't installed.

Comment: Something isn't right with this, I'm using `aptitude search '!~M ~i'` and it lists 1043 packages. There is no way I installed that many packages manually.

Comment: This definitely doesn't work as requested, prints pre-installed packages as well.

Comment: @GraemeDonaldson & Irfy: I think there's a bug in Ubuntu(?), under some conditions it lists system packages as packages installed manually. I'm seeing the same on my system (check with synaptic), where I have packages like "accountservice" listed as manually installed and I am certain I did not install it manually.

Comment: On my system, `aptitude search '!~M ~i'` shows exactly 1583 lines, many more than also I expected. But so does `apt-mark showmanual`, so at least they agree.

Comment: Unaccepting this answer, because as everyone has pointed out, it doesn't actually seem to work. However, the other answer don't seem to work either. I don't need a solution right now (this is a very old question), but to keep this accurate, I will accept any answer that actually works well.

Answer (score 11):

I would like to give a GUI solution.

[image]

1. Open Synaptic Package Manager.
2. Go to *Status*.
3. Click *Installed (manual)*.

It will give the list of packages installed manually by `apt` or `aptitude`.

Unfortunately I could not find any option in *Custom Filters* to find out whether a `foobar` package was installed manually or automatically.

If the package is under *Installed* but not under *Installed (manual)*, then it was installed automatically. If the package is under *Installed (manual)*, then it was installed manually.

Answer (score 10):

The following script will print out all the packages that are not set to automatic install and hence were installed manually:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

try:
    import apt_pkg
except ImportError:
    print("Error importing apt_pkg, is python-apt installed?")
    sys.exit(1)

apt_pkg.init()
STATE_FILE = apt_pkg.config.find_dir("Dir::State") + "extended_states"
auto = set()
tagfile = apt_pkg.TagFile(open(STATE_FILE))
while tagfile.step():
    pkgname = tagfile.section.get("Package")
    autoInst = tagfile.section.get("Auto-Installed")
    if not int(autoInst):
        auto.add(pkgname)
print("\n".join(sorted(auto)))
```

it is based on how apt-mark prints out the automatically installed packages.

Comment: Kudos to you fine sir. This actually works, in contrast to the accepted answer.

Comment: show just a couple of package for me --- definitely missing a lot of them.

Comment: Same here, definitely missing manually installed packages, right after I installed them.

Comment: Using `sys.exit(1)` without `import sys` might result in an error in newer versions of python. Either `import sys` or use `exit(1)`.

Answer (score 5):

As several people have commented, apt-mark showmanual seems to be a bit buggy (and I reported it as [bug 727799](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=727799)). When I'm using it, it actually reports a lot of stuff that isn't even logged in /var/lib/apt/extended_states (where this is supposed to be stored) and apt-get isn't logging things as installed in /var/lib/apt/extended_states (just in /var/lib/dpkg/status). The python script by txwikinger above draws from /var/lib/apt/extended_states directly but if you're using it today the syntax might not work (mine just started generating errors with Kubuntu 13.10). Updated syntax is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

try:
    import apt_pkg
except ImportError:
    print "Error importing apt_pkg, is python-apt installed?"
    sys.exit(1)

apt_pkg.init()
STATE_FILE = apt_pkg.config.find_dir("Dir::State") + "extended_states"
auto = set()
tagfile = apt_pkg.TagFile(open(STATE_FILE))
while tagfile.step():
    pkgname = tagfile.section.get("Package")
    autoInst = tagfile.section.get("Auto-Installed")
    if not int(autoInst):
        auto.add(pkgname)
print "\n".join(sorted(auto))
```

For me this was a very short list of 5 items which doesn't seem to be accurate either.

Comment: Using `sys.exit(1)` without `import sys` might result in an error in newer versions of python. Either `import sys` or use `exit(1)`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're **in a VM (Virtual Machine)**, then the following might work better for you:

```
egrep 'apt(-get)? +install' /var/log/apt/history.log
```

That finds software you installed both via `apt` and `apt-get`. If you'd like to include `aptitude` too, this should work:

```
egrep 'apt(-get|itude)? +install' /var/log/apt/history.log
```

(But don't think this'd find packages installed directly via `dpkg` — which I don't really do anyway.)

**Rationale**: If the Virtual Machine already included some default software installed by the VM maintainers (in the base image), but not by you, then, this answer won't show the software they installed (well at least not in the VMs I'm using), only the software you installed.

The other answers here, which uses e.g. `apt-mark showmanual` or `aptitude search '!~M ~i'` or `apt list --manual-installed`, in my case, in a VM, showed 90% to me uninteresting packages that I didn't install — instead, some of the VM base image maintainers did (I presume).

Comment: This is true. I used `history | egrep 'apt(-get|itude)? +install'`

Comment: I think your search expression misses `apt -y install`.

Answer (score 2):

If no one gives you a nice answer using a apr-something command you can do it the *hard way*. Apt-get stores its info in /var/lib/apt/extended_states. Any file that is installed automatically will be added to this file. If you install a package already in this file manually, the package will remain in this file but with Auto-installed: 0 in the second line. It's not deleted.

Note: As expected better answers that are likely to work if file placement changes have appeared. I keep mine just in case the info on the file location is useful.

Comment: No. I took a quick look at that file to find that liferea was marked as auto-installed. I did an `apt-get install liferea` and it didn't install but I got output that was something to the effect of "marked as manually installed". Now liferea is still in the file, except the next line has a `0` instead of a `1`. Also, you should change your regex pattern to `" foobar$"` instead of just `foobar`.

Comment: That's true. My fault, in my system there is no line with 0, but it should be a rare happening. I update the answer just in case.

Answer (score 2):

After googling a lot, I've managed to assemble this script. It works alright for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

# List of all packages currently installed
current=$(dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq)

# List of all packages that were installed with the system
pre=$(gzip -dc /var/log/installer/initial-status.gz | sed -n 's/^Package: //p' | sort | uniq)

# List of packages that don't depend on any other package
manual=$(apt-mark showmanual | sort | uniq)

# (Current - Pre) ∩ (Manual)
packages=$(comm -12 <(comm -23 <(echo "$current") <(echo "$pre")) <(echo "$manual") )

for pack in $packages; do
    packname=$(echo $pack | cut -f 1 -d ":")
    desc=$(apt-cache search "^$packname$" | sed -E 's/.* - (.*)/\1/')
    date=$(date -r /var/lib/dpkg/info/$pack.list)

    echo "# $desc"
    echo "# $date"
    echo "sudo apt-get install $pack"
    echo -e ""
done
```

Comment: You could use `sort -u` instead of `sort | unique`.  As `apt-mark`does not display architecture, you should strip it from dpkg's output before the set operations (or use `dpkg-query -W -f='${Package}\n'`). Besides, dpkg may list some packages that are not installed currently. As for "desc", you could use `dpkg-query -W -f='# ${binary:Summary}\n' $pack, which is faster.

Comment: Oh, `apt-mark`may display architecture for some packages, but not for so many as `dpkg -l`.

Comment: `apt-cache search` is slow. Getting a list of installed dates in advance using something like https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ListInstalledPackagesByDate might be more efficient

Answer (score 2):

An updated version of @jmiserez' answer:

```sh
comm -23 \
    <(apt-mark showmanual | sort -u) \
    <(grep -oP '^(?:Package|Depends):\s+\K.*' /var/log/installer/status \
        | grep -oP '[^\s,()]+?(?=(?:\s+\([^)]+\))?+(?:,|$))' \
        | sort -u)
```

The log is no longer stored at `/var/log/installer/initial-status.gz` and the original did not omit dependent packages. The list it produces will include packages you didn't manually install, but it's a more manageable length and still very useful.

Comment: The answers that are based on initial-status.gz (or in this case its equivalent) are the best here, but become increasingly irrelevant if you have upgraded the installation to new releases over the years because new packages brought in by the upgrades will be included.  I feel a similar solution using the current version's manifest file might be more useful in such cases

Answer (score 2):

Compiled from the awesome answers by others in this thread and additional info from the internet I assembled a command that fits my needs and perfectly replicates my apt history:

`ls /var/log/apt/history.log* | sort --version-sort | xargs -d '\n' zgrep -B 1 'Commandline: apt'`

So, first of all, it outputs history in chronological order, e.g.

```
/var/log/apt/history.log.1
/var/log/apt/history.log.2
...
/var/log/apt/history.log.10
```

You can add `--reverse` param to the sort to sort files in reverse order. That way you'll have oldest commands on the top of the list.
Plus it has date of the command.

Kudos to @s1037989 and @iruvar

Answer (score 1):

As Li Lo said, `apt-mark showauto` should get you a fat list of things automatically installed.

Now to show the things that are installed manually, it turns out there's a lovely simple search modifier for aptitude. But you don't want to to do that. You want to write a huge bash command that does some rocket science.

***Note:** This is more an illustration of how cool you'll look busting out massive bash commands to all your friends.*

```
comm -3  <(dpkg-query --show -f '${Package} ${Status}\n' | \n
grep "install ok installed" | cut --delimiter=' ' -f 1) <(apt-mark showauto)
```

I broke it onto two lines for readability. What does this do?

- First we query dpkg for a list of packages that are installed.
- We filter those for the ones that are actually installed (not just residual config)
- We chop off the status
- We compare that list with the automated list from `apt-mark`
- We rock out because we can.

Comment: I doubt this is accurate, since dpkg often shows packages that are not installed

Comment: I know what you mean but my bash-fu isn't strong enough. I know you could show the status from dpkg-query, grep that down and then slice off the status. I'll have a go.

Comment: `comm -3  <(dpkg -l | grep '^ii' | cut -d \  -f 3|sort) <(apt-mark showauto|sort)` is properly better ;)

Answer (score 1):

This gets you a list of manual installed packages and its corresponding version

```
apt list --manual-installed | sed 's/\// /' | awk '{print $1 "=" $3}'
```

Comment: Really should be MUCH higher voted!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful, but to find packages that were recently installed manually by the current user, search the history. E.g., for `bash`:

```bsh
$ history | egrep '\bapt\b'
```

Modify the grep to check for specific packages.

Comment: Not sure why this answer doesn't have more love. All the other answers here gave me a list that included lots of dependencies or didn't work. This is simple, and as long as your history is maintained, it's sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed all your packages from the terminal using apt, you could throw a simple regex searching for `apt install *` at the contents of `/var/log/apt/history.log` and see what it gobbles up.
The regex might be as simple as: `Commandline: apt install [\w -]+` (following the log syntax of apt on Ubuntu 16.04)

Answer (score 0):

From Ubuntu 22.04 and onwards, you could take care of this using a more modern `apt` front-end called `nala` (for 22.04 you have to enable the "universe" repository).

```
sudo apt install nala
```

From this point, use `nala` to install new packages on your system, using:

```
sudo nala install <package-name>
```

Leave security updates etc. to the `unattended-upgrades` package.

Now, when you run the command `nala history`, you get a list of the commands run with nala, including installed packages. To filter only new installations, use:

```
nala history | grep install
```

An added bonus of the history feature is that you can undo any step in the history, so that you can reverse package installation procedures - something that is unnecessarily hard using `apt` itself.

Answer (score -1):

I have found an elegant method for doing this.

Just output the `~/.bash_history` file with the `grep` command to sort them out:

```
cat .bash_history | grep "apt install"
```

Conveniently, you can look out for an `apt-get` too.

An example output, I have:

```
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt install vim 
sudo apt install dconf
sudo apt install dconf-editors
sudo apt install dconf-editor
sudo apt install nmap
sudo apt install python-tk
sudo apt install python-tk
```

Answer (score -2):

This will list all manually installed packages without: dependencies, uninstalled packages, packages installed during system installation.

```bsh
unopts() {
  in=`cat`
  echo "$in" | sed -r 's/ --[^ ]+//g;s/ -[^ ]+//g'
}

list() {
  cat '/var/log/apt/history.log' |
  grep --color=never -v '\-o APT::Status-Fd=4 \-o APT::Keep-Fds::=5 \-o APT::Keep-Fds::=6' |
  egrep --color=never "Commandline: apt-get.* $1" |
  sed -r "s/Commandline: apt-get//;s/ $1//" |
  unopts |
  tr ' ' '\n' |
  sed '/^$/d'
}

hapt() {
  tmp=`mktemp -d`
  installed=$tmp/installed
  deleted=$tmp/deleted
  dpkg=$tmp/dpkg
  list 'install' > $installed
  list '(remove|purge|autoremove)' > $deleted
  dpkg --get-selections |
  grep -v 'deinstall' |
  cut -f 1 > $dpkg
  while read package
  do
    sed -i "0,/$package/{//d;}" $installed
  done < $deleted
  while read package
  do
    if [ -z "`grep --color=never "^$package$" $dpkg`" ]
    then
      sed -i "0,/$package/{//d;}" $installed
    fi
  done < $installed
  cat $installed
  rm -r $tmp
}
```