# How to view a list of packages that were manually installed without their dependancies

Tags: apt, package-management, metapackages

How do I see a list of packages I manually (really manually, as in I typed them in) installed?

I want to exclude packages that were installed as a result of being dependencies of other packages that I manually typed in.

For example, if I ran the command:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

and as a result *mysql-common* was installed, I want to **only** see *mysql-server* in the list and not *mysql-common*.

I've searched for an answer and found many that were close but not exactly what I want.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/880805

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That do what you want:

```
cat /var/log/apt/history.log | grep -E 'apt(-get)? install '
```

Comment: That's a very clever answer. The only flaw is the history is limited because of log rotation. This solution would be more robust if you went into the archived logs and pulled out those log entries as well. That being said, your idea sounds great. Thanks.

Comment: To accommodate log rotation you can search old log files too. Use
`$ zcat /var/log/apt/history.log.*.gz | grep 'apt-get install'`

Comment: `zcat /var/log/apt/history.log.*.gz | grep 'apt-get install'` did give me a list of things I installed but surely not the whole list.

Comment: Or, if you use `apt` to install things: cat /var/log/apt/history.log | grep 'apt install '

Answer (score 17):

It's much better to use *apt-mark* tool:

```
apt-mark showmanual
```

This is exactly what you want. You also can mark packages as manually installed or not and hold the packages on fixed versions.

Comment: This shows dependencies installed along with the manually installed packages.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: @ToDo, is it? Or is it listing packages "manually" installed during OS installation? I saw a lot of packages that I didn't explicitly install but I thought they were "manually" installed when I installed the OS.

Answer (score 0):

I've built a script using the idea of wojox. It creates file in your home directory with all packages in it.

https://github.com/PaperMountainStudio/list-manually-installed-packages