# Write List of Packages installed via Manual Invocation of apt-get to File

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, synaptic

I'm trying to install a new version of Ubuntu from scratch, but I would like a list of the packages which I manually installed (as opposed to installed as a dependency or that came with the system).

I can get a reasonable approximation on Synaptic by looking at only my `Installed (manual)` packages and then only looking at those packages *not* supported by Ubuntu (i.e. all those files without the Ubuntu Unity symbol next to them). However, I cannot seem to get Synaptic to export a list of these packages.

Hence my question is whether it is possible to generate a list of packages that were installed manually via the `apt-get install` command?

The following do *not* work:

- Using `apt-mark showmanual`. It yields all packages deemed essential as well as manually installed packages. I only want my manually installed packages.
- `aptitude search '!~M ~i'`. There are *way* too many packages that are being shown (no way I manually installed > 1000 packages).
- The Python script given by @txwikinger in [Generating list of manually installed packages and querying individual packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2389/generating-list-of-manually-installed-packages-and-querying-individual-packages). There are packages (such as `bsdgames`) which I installed, but do not show up in the output of that script.
- The bash script given by @Johan in https://serverfault.com/questions/133681/generating-a-list-of-installed-packages-in-ubuntu. Once again too many packages are shown.

This question is similar in flavor to other questions that have been asked both on Stack Exchange sites and elsewhere (such as [Generating list of manually installed packages and querying individual packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2389/generating-list-of-manually-installed-packages-and-querying-individual-packages), https://serverfault.com/questions/133681/generating-a-list-of-installed-packages-in-ubuntu, and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=947865&page=2).

David Kalnischkies on http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=727799 gives some perspective as to why pinning down exactly what "manually installed" means is difficult (e.g. do programs which you ran which installed packages count as "manually installed"?). Therefore I have specifically limited this question (unlike the others that I listed) to only invocations of `apt-get install`.

Edit: [How to view a list of packages that were manually installed without their dependancies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195782/how-to-view-a-list-of-packages-that-were-manually-installed-without-their-depend?rq=1) has a nice idea for using the log files of apt-get to do this. Unfortunately this doesn't keep track of which packages have been removed. And even if I were to simply `grep 'apt-get purge'` and take the `diff` of the two lists that I get it still wouldn't account for the edge case that I've installed a package, uninstalled it, and then reinstalled it.

Comment: If you are still interested, check out my solution in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/492343/145754).

Answer (score 2):

Since no answer using *apt* has been found, I would suggest going into [Synaptic Package Manager](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/synaptic-package-manager-beginners-guide-for-ubuntu-users.html), click on the Status button at lower left then click on Installed (manual) at upper left to see a list of installed packages.

[image: List from Synaptic of installed packages]

Then you can output a list from Synaptic with `File | Save Markings As` and save the file where you can work with it.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this solution. It deserves to be acknowledged at par with any other _cool_ CLI-based solution! One correction though, OP asked for the list of all _manually installed_ packages, so in the LHS panel, **Installed (manual)** must be selected before saving the markings. Kudos for a simple & elegant approach! :)

Answer (score 0):

I just posted this thought on an earlier page about this, sorry if that's impolite (feel free to remove this if it is) but

1. go get the "manifest" file for your version of Ubuntu at http://releases.ubuntu.com/
   as far as I understand it that lists all packages that are in a stock install.
2. do `apt-mark showmanual` to generate a list of all packages apt-mark considers to have been manually installed.
3. eliminate the dups between that list and the manifest, leaving the packages in the output of `apt-mark showmanual` that were not part of the stock installation.

Probably this is crude and doesn't deal with the subtlties of what exactly constitutes a "manually installed" package, but to me it looks like a pretty good approximation. Or maybe the Synaptic solution is the best.