# Generating list of installed localization packages

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, locale, localization

I need to find out just the packages installed for current locales. That packages, which are installed if you open the Language support in the System settings after fresh installation of Ubuntu. They are usually packages installing localized strings and help into the preinstalled packages and also some packages serving localization of Ubuntu.

I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/492343/369427) pretty cool trick how to list manually installed packages and localization packages. But I need just to list the localization ones.

The output of that cool trick looks like:

```
brackets
build-essential
fluxgui
folder-color
gitg
gnome-paint
google-chrome-stable
hunspell-en-ca
hyphen-en-us
language-pack-gnome-cs
libgmp-dev
libkrb5-dev
libnss3-dev
liboxideqtquick0
libpcap-dev
libreoffice-help-cs
libreoffice-help-en-gb
libreoffice-l10n-en-gb
libreoffice-l10n-en-za
libssl-dev
linux-headers-3.13.0-44
linux-headers-3.13.0-44-generic
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-44-generic
linux-image-3.13.0-44-generic
maxthon-browser-stable
myspell-cs
myspell-en-au
myspell-en-gb
myspell-en-za
mythes-cs
mythes-en-au
mythes-en-us
openjdk-6-jre
openjdk-7-jre
openoffice.org-hyphenation
pipelight-multi
python-requests
thunderbird-locale-cs
thunderbird-locale-en
thunderbird-locale-en-gb
thunderbird-locale-en-us
ttf-mscorefonts-installer
vlc
wbritish
wine1.6
wine1.7
yasm
```

But I need just these (probably):

```
hunspell-en-ca
hyphen-en-us
language-pack-gnome-cs
libreoffice-help-cs
libreoffice-help-en-gb
libreoffice-l10n-en-gb
libreoffice-l10n-en-za
myspell-cs
myspell-en-au
myspell-en-gb
myspell-en-za
mythes-cs
mythes-en-au
mythes-en-us
openoffice.org-hyphenation
thunderbird-locale-cs
thunderbird-locale-en
thunderbird-locale-en-gb
thunderbird-locale-en-us
wbritish
```

somehow automatically. Could you help me please?

Comment: I'm not aware of an easy method to pick only those. Why do you need it? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have 85 computers with clean installation, where I just need to install the same localization, so I want to write simple (in a few lines) bash script to install them just to execute on each, but I don't know, which packages are for localization and which not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you selected English when installing, these commands ought to add all the language and language support packages for both Czech and English:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/locale-langpack/cs
sudo apt-get install $(check-language-support)
```

Comment: Looks like universal solution, thank you. (I selected Czech, but there isn't full Czech localization in the original Trusty iso and I cannot connect that computers to internet during installation)