# How to list all packages installed as dependencies in Terminal, and what installed them?

Tags: command-line, dependencies, installed-programs

Is there a way in Terminal to list all programs which have not been installed by me, but other programs as necessary dependencies? And can I at the same time view which programs they were installed by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `aptitude` a high-level interface to the package manager, but you have to install it first

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

After that

```
aptitude search '?installed(?automatic)'
```

to see a list of automatically installed packages.

---

And to see at the same time which programs they were installed by:

- Only `Depends`

  ```
  aptitude -F %p search '?installed(?automatic)' | \
      while read x ; do aptitude why "$x" | awk '/Depends/' ; done
  ```
- Or the full list

  ```
  aptitude -F %p search '?installed(?automatic)' | \
      while read x ; do aptitude why "$x"; done
  ```

*Sample output*

```
i   texlive-full   Depends lcdf-typetools
i A lcdf-typetools Depends aglfn         
i   python3-apparmor-click Depends apparmor-easyprof
i   aptitude Depends aptitude-common (= 0.6.11-1ubuntu3)
i   arronax Depends arronax-base
i   arronax Depends arronax-nautilus
i   ubuntu-dev-tools Depends    devscripts (>= 2.11.0~)
i   lxc-docker       Depends    lxc-docker-1.7.1
i   gnome-common Depends autopoint
i A nvidia-prime Depends    bbswitch-dkms                    
i   calibre            Depends python-pil | python-imaging      
i A python-pil         Depends mime-support | python-pil.imagetk
i A python-pil.imagetk Depends python-tk (>= 2.7.7-2)           
i A python-tk          Depends blt (>= 2.4z-9)                  
i   bluegriffon Depends bluegriffon-data (= 1.7.2-1~getdeb2~raring)
i   playonlinux Depends cabextract
```

Comment: That gives me the description of the dependencies in addition, however does not appear to show which application installed it.

Comment: You have changed your question :\

Comment: I made an improvement to it, however I did it before you posted your answer, so I assumed that you had seen my edits.

Comment: I didn't know that! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Closely related to: [Generating list of manually installed packages and querying individual packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2389/generating-list-of-manually-installed-packages-and-querying-individual-packages)

Use:

```
apt-mark showauto
```

This lists *automatically* installed packages, as opposed to *manually* installed packages.

Comment: And can I at the same time view which programs they were installed by?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda at the same time? Doubtful. You can try `aptitude why` on these packages.

Comment: How about something along the lines of `for i in $(apt-mark showauto); do aptitude why "$i"; done`? ;-) Admittedly, the output is rather confusing (though that's easily remedied), and it will take a hell of a long time...

Comment: @ParanoidPanda adapting on Malte's suggestion: `apt-mark showauto | xargs -n1 aptitude why`

Answer (score 1):

Use this pipe in your command line: `apt list --installed | xargs apt-cache showpkg > dependencies.txt`. Beware it will take long and use all your cpu. I piped it to a file because it is a very long list. The first part of the pipe provides all installed packages, the second part takes each one of them and looks for their dependencies.