# How to view history of apt-get install?

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, history

How can I view the history of `apt-get install` commands that I have manually executed?

It seems to me that all methods available show everything that has been installed right from the start of the Ubuntu installation.

How can I view the history of `apt-get install` since the time my system-installation process had completed?

Comment: Well, yes. What else would you expect? Do you want to show only those you ran from the terminal and not those that were run by a GUI or something? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: @terdon Okay made a new edit

Comment: There are logs of `dpkg` in `/var/log/dpkg.log*`.

Comment: You could also try just running `history | grep "apt-get install"`.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda That fails in various ways. History truncations, things run in other shells, things removed from history, or never put there in the first place, things installed from scripts, things run by other users etc etc

Comment: @MrBones: I know, and I have stated so in [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/680441/364819) (and in the comments below it). However the OP asked for a way to view all the instances when they have manually executed the `apt-get install` command to install a package, and I have provided a solution which gives this information unless the history file has been altered in certain ways (e.g.: the entries have been removed).

Comment: DevRobot please verify my answer as well ,whether you are getting your desired answer,

Comment: Related (probably duplicate): [How do I show apt-get package management history via command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21657/how-do-i-show-apt-get-package-management-history-via-command-line)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think the answer given [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/680405/320386) by [kos](https://askubuntu.com/users/380067/kos) is the best way I've seen so far.
Though as Software Center uses `apt`, anything that it has installed would be listed too.

The command is:

```
zcat /var/log/apt/history.log.*.gz | cat - /var/log/apt/history.log | grep -Po '^Commandline: apt-get install (?!.*--reinstall)\K.*'
```

Comment: I'll test this out when I get home and accept it if it works **:)**

Comment: It's not! check out the update: http://askubuntu.com/a/680405/320386

Comment: Use this, is way more safer for this task: `zcat /var/log/apt/history.log.*.gz | cat - /var/log/apt/history.log | grep -Po '^Commandline:(?=.* install ) \K.*' | sed '1,4d'`: `grep -Po '^Commandline:(?=.* install ) \K.*'` will filter only the `apt-get` commands containing `install` with a leading and trailing space, `sed '1,4d'` *might* be dependant on the specific installation; in mine `1,4` deletes exactly the number of entries coming from Ubiquity, which are those you want to remove. Let me know if the number is the same on your installation, that way at least we have a baseline :|

Comment: @kos I get extra lines such as `apt-get -o APT::Status-Fd=4 -o APT::Keep-Fds::=5 -o APT::Keep-Fds::=6 -q -y --no-remove install linux-generic` with the new command. Are they the Ubiquity lines?

Comment: No, those look like they came from Software Updater; there's no way to distinguish from commands run from the user and commands run by some `apt-get` frontend, aside from Ubiquity which runs only once (for example `aptdaemon` entries will be showed by that command as well). The best bet though is still to use that command, which at least excludes the Ubiquity entries.

Comment: However just to know if deleting the first 4 lines is always safe, could you confirm that `zcat /var/log/apt/history.log.*.gz | cat - /var/log/apt/history.log | grep -Po '^Commandline:(?=.* install ) \K.*' | sed -n '1,4p'` outputs something similiar to [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12637949/)? (The first two entries don't wrap but they're *massive*).

Comment: No it doesn't, it outputs only the first 4 lines of the 12 packages that I've installed. Each of these 4 lines starts with 'apt-get install' then just the package name. @kos

Comment: Quite strange, maybe 15.04 is different (I'm assuming you're not running 15.04 because this is about the third time I reinstall 15.04 and the start of the very first log is always identical). Well then no luck, there's no way at all to parse those logs safely. Thanks

Comment: Yeah I'm running 14.04, the command that I've copied in the answer works for me, but having only installed 12 package manually, I suppose I can't guarantee it'll work for everyone!

Comment: You could also install with `apt install`, or use more than one space between words.

Answer (score 13):

Just type following command in your terminal to view all install logs.

```
grep " install " /var/log/dpkg.log
```

Comment: This is even better than the accepted solution since it lists all the packets installed, dependencies included.

Answer (score 5):

To simplify @Arronical answer, A neat trick I learned recently is you can use `zcat -qf` to cat both txt and txt gzipped files.

```
zcat /var/log/apt/history.log.*.gz | cat - /var/log/apt/history.log | grep " install "
```

becomes

```
zcat -qf /var/log/apt/history.log* | grep " install "
```

From man zcat:

```
   -q --quiet
          Suppress all warnings.
   -f --force
          Force  compression  or  decompression  even if the file has multiple links or the corre‐
          sponding file already exists, or if the compressed data is read from  or  written  to  a
          terminal.  If  the  input  data is not in a format recognized by gzip, and if the option
          --stdout is also given, copy the input data without change to the standard  output:  let
          zcat  behave  as  cat.  If -f is not given, and when not running in the background, gzip
          prompts to verify whether an existing file should be overwritten.
```

Comment: As [I comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/680410/how-to-view-history-of-apt-get-install/680417#comment2067316_680417) there are other cases. Maybe the best way is just `zcat -qf /var/log/apt/history.log* | grep " install "`

Answer (score 3):

Here is script which prints only the currently installed **top level packages**, where "top level packages" are defined as apt packages upon which no other apt packages depend. If such top level programs were installed by apt or a package manager such as Synaptic, then they were manually chosen by the user.

```
#!/bin/sh
NumDaysAgo=18
find /var/lib/dpkg/info -name "*.list" -mtime -$NumDaysAgo \
    -exec stat -c $'%y\t%n' {} \; | \
sed -e 's,/var/lib/dpkg/info/,,' -e 's,\.list,,' | \
sort -r | \
while read Date Time Xxx Pkg
do 
    lncnt=$(apt-cache --installed rdepends $Pkg | wc -l)
    if [ $lncnt -eq "2" ]
        then echo "$Date $Time $Pkg"
    fi
done
echo "JOB COMPLETED: $BASH_SOURCE"
```

The packages are printed in reverse order under the assumption that the user is more likely to want the newer info sooner, and because the program is slow.

**Program flow:**

- The program first gathers into a list all the installed packages by reading the filenames under `/var/lib/dpkg/info/`.  The file mod times are the installation times.
- That list is sorted in reverse order.
- For each installed package `$Pkg`, a call to `apt-cache rdepends $Pkg`
  requests the reverse-dependencies of `$Pkg`.  If there are no dependencies, then it is a top level package and the package info is printed: *date time packagename*

**Notes:**

- The script depends upon the output format of `apt-cache rdepends $Pkg` which was intended for human eyes and could change in the future versions of apt.
- The code for the part gathering filenames under /var/lib/dpkg/info/ came from
  [this unix.stackexchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12579). As that poster *'mikel'* pointed out, the `dpgk` history logfiles are not reliable because they will be rotated out after reaching a certain volume.
- Man page for 
  [`apt-cache`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/apt-cache.8.html)
- The call `apt-cache rdepends ...` is very slow presumably because each call is computed by  iterating through all the dependencies.  Hence the above script starts from the newest installs to offer the user as much instant gratification as possible.
- The `--installed` flag after `apt-cache` checks that the dpkg-installed packages are also apt-installed.  If the user or another install software bypassed apt and used dpkg directly, it would be possible.  THIS CASE HAS NOT BEEN TESTED, but I think something noticeable would be printed in either the standard or error output
- The output does not include manually chosen packages which later became  depended upon by a higher package.  The output can also include packages which were installed via apt by other third party install software, and hence are not truly manually installed.  However, if the purpose of the output is as a basis for setting up a restored Linux from a backup `/home` directory which included said third party software, then this output would be suitable.
- Some of the package names include version numbers, and some do not.  Mentioned just to bring awareness to the fact.

Answer (score 1):

If you want history of `apt-get install` commands use the following command:

```
grep "apt-get install" .bash_history
```

Output:

```
ravan@ravan:~$ grep "apt-get install" .bash_history
```

---

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-mate-core ubuntu-mate-desktop
sudo apt-get install xfce4
sudo apt-get install xfce4.12
sudo apt-get install pgadmin
sudo apt-get install touchegg
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo gedit .bash_history | grep "apt-get install" 
sudo apt-get installvim
grep "apt-get install" .bash_history
cat .bash_history | grep "apt-get install"
```

For other information refer[Extra information](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ListInstalledPackagesByDate).

There is also more detailed installation information in `/var/log/apt/` in the `history.log` and `history.log.X.gz` files and `term.log` and `term.log.X.gz` files

If you want history of only `apt-get` included commands, then

```
history | grep apt-get
```

---

Comment: `apt-mark showmanual` shows all packages installed when the OS was installed too, rather than just those actually manually installed. It's an odd way for it to behave!

Comment: This doesn't necessarily give specific details as to the history.  What people *need* to look at is `/var/log/apt/history.log` and similar files.  You only get the list of manually selected and autoselected packages.  You don't give *any* chronological history of what was installed, what was removed, what was upgraded, etc. from this answer.

Comment: @Arronical - Where is the man page for `apt -mark showmanual`?  I can't see it on the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS man page for `apt`:
 <http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt.8.html>.

Comment: @CraigHicks http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt-mark.8.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want see all of the things you have installed by running:

```
sudo apt-get install [package]
```

And you have not messed with the bash history, nor are you wanting to view the history of this sort of installation type for another user (or all users) then you can just run:

```
history | grep "apt-get install"
```

And that should get you mostly relevant results.

Comment: Will I get **all** the history with this?

Comment: @DevRobot: Unless you have manually altered the entries with the `apt-get install` in them in the `.bash_history` file, or deleted this file, the command will show you all the instances when you have executed a command with the string `apt-get install` within it on your user account (even if you run the command as root and therefore not exactly as your user account - that is running a command with `sudo`).

Comment: It might have a problem if you've entered more than 200 commands though

Comment: @Arronical proof is expected when making claims ;-)

Comment: @Arronical: Really? I did not know that there was a limit of 200 commands in the `.bash_history` file and there certainly isn't such a limit on my system. Could you please clarify what you mean.

Comment: I myself would assume 500 to be the default ( http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Facilities.html ).

Comment: Oops I meant 2000 commands, which I think is the default number of commands displayed by the `history` command, but I may have imagined this! Looking now...

Comment: `history` displays the number of commands, from your`.bash_history` file, specified by the `$HISTSIZE` environment variable. It seems to be set to 1000 as default in 14.04 server installations. @Rinzwind , cheers for getting me to check!

Answer (score 0):

In order to see what You've installed and removed, reinstalled, etc. More info about the *journey* of apt-get installs.

The answer can be modified into an alias:

```
alias apted='zcat /var/log/apt/history.log.*.gz | cat - /var/log/apt/history.log | fgrep Commandline: | cut -d " " -f 2- | grep -P "^|install"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that some arguments can be set before the install one, like the virtualmin script is doing during install: apt-get -y install packagename.

So if you want capture all install commands, you need to change the regex query.

```
zcat -qf /var/log/apt/history.log* | grep -Po '^Commandline: apt-get.*install (?!.*--reinstall)\K.*'
```