# How to list all manually installed packages?

Tags: apt, dpkg

I want to list all packages that are *not* automatically installed as dependencies.

E.g. I've installed `build-essential`, whose dependencies include `gcc`.  I want to output a list that contains `build-essential`, but not `gcc`.

Comment: I think this sort of question already asked http://askubuntu.com/questions/2389/generating-list-of-manually-installed-packages-and-querying-individual-packages This link may help you.

Comment: @DharaniDharan Thanks, `apt-mark showmanual` is what I'm looking for.