# Move all stuff to a new ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I'm new to ubuntu. If I wanted to install ubuntu on another computer, how can I move all stuff on my old installation to the new one?

Should I just use `tar` in terminal to pack my old `/*`, and then unpack it in the new `/*`? Does it work? Or should I just move the /home to the new one?

Because on my old installation, I have already installed many developer tools, and I don't want to reinstall the whole system.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

My approach: Use deja-dup to back up and transfer my data, and [aptik](https://launchpad.net/apt-toolkit) to back up and transfer my installed software.  I've used this several times.  Not flawless, but close.

Comment: It's a good approach,aptik seems can't backup the pip,npm,rubygems package

Answer (score 0):

You could tar up your /home/ directory to get all your config, but on I wouldn't tar up your / directory and try to restore it to another.  To get your new host in the same setup as the current, you could always look in the /var/log/apt/history.log file on the old host to see all the packages you have installed and re-install them on the new one.

Another option would be to use [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/) to make a copy of your hard drive onto another.  It is a live CD that lets you copy a hard drive.

Comment: My `/var/log/apt/history.log` only goes back two weeks.

Comment: Thx. so helpful.but I once used npm,pip tools to install package,so the clonezilla is a better option?

Comment: Here's a better way to [list all packages that you installed](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2389/generating-list-of-manually-installed-packages-and-querying-individual-packages).