# How can I find all the additional packages I installed?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

is there a way to get a list of all the package names I have installed **additionally** to those that shipped with my copy of Ubuntu?

I didn't find options under the manual files of `apt`, `dpkg` and `apt-get` that seemed like they could do this kind of function.

EDIT to clarify: assuming Ubuntu came with packages *a,b,c,d,e,f* and I manually installed packages *x,y,z*, how can I get a list of *x,y,z*?

Comment: Do a minimum research before asking, or if you did, make clear what you have tried, even if that didnt work out http://askubuntu.com/questions/2389/generating-list-of-manually-installed-packages-and-querying-individual-packages/492343#492343

Comment: @M.Becerra manually and automatically is different things than the question OP asked. Ubuntu mark all packages it installed by default as manual and that is not going to help

Comment: @M.Becerra thank you, the commands in the answer there seem to be what i needed. I tried searching but had difficulty phrasing myself so resorted to making my own question; sorry/thanks!

Comment: I'm voting this to reopen because, I think this is **not a duplicate** of the linked question. Reasons are 1. apt's manual and automatic are not same as manually installed by me and automatically installed by default. These are very different.

Comment: @maze88 What do you mean by "I manually installed". Manually has two meanings in Apt world. If you install a package A and it brings B, C as dependencies, Only A is marked as manually installed. You want to see all A,B,C in the output or only the A?

Comment: @Anwar Thank you for pointing this out. My goal was to have a list of what packages to reinstall if setting up a new system, so A would be sufficient.

Comment: @maze88 OK then.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there are better ways to do this, but this works.

First download the Ubuntu manifest file for your Ubuntu release

```
wget -c "releases.ubuntu.com/$(lsb_release -r -s)/ubuntu-$(lsb_release -r -s)-desktop-$(dpkg --print-architecture).manifest" -O ubuntu.manifest
```

Then generate the list of packages you have in your system and save it in a file called `installed`

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${binary:Package}\t${Version}\n' > installed
```

Then copy and paste this python code to a file naming `pkg-diff.py` (or whatever name you want)

```python
f = open('ubuntu.manifest', 'r')

default = []
for line in f:
  default.append(line.split('\t')[0])

f2 = open('installed', 'r')
installed = []
for line in f2:
  installed.append(line.split('\t')[0])

extras = list(set(installed) - set(default))

print("\n".join(extras))
```

Finally execute the python script using the command in a terminal.

```
python3 ./pkg-diff.py
```

It should give you the list of packages you installed additionally.

**Note:** All files should be in same directory.

Comment: Cool solution!  ;-)