# How to uninstall package on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, uninstall, gnome-shell-extension

I accidentally installed this app in Ubuntu. Now I want to uninstall it, but I forgot its name. How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find all the additional packages I installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/842846/how-can-i-find-all-the-additional-packages-i-installed)

Comment: The method to remove is the reverse of how you installed it, or specific to the type of app.  If it was a snap, `snap remove`, if a deb package, `apt remove` etc.  If an extension for gnome, it can be removed by the gnome-linked browser, or....  You've however tagged an EOL/ESM release which is now off-topic here.

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in extended support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades
https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

Comment: @guiverc, I thought 14.04 LTS is EOL in April 2022 (see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes 14.04 ESM is EOL on April 2022 with *extended support* enabled, however 14.04 LTS when installed from ISO provides only *standard support* which has ended support already, refer https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/ provided earlier. Convention here (*as I understand it*) is only *standard support* is on-topic, *extended* is Ubuntu Advantage provided elsewhere, though it's been, and is currently being discussed https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19510/is-ubuntu-14-04-off-topic-on-ask-ubuntu/19529#19529

Comment: @ali Raza Canonical, the maker of Ubuntu will continue to support 14.04 and 16.04 through Extended Security Maintenance until April 2024. Ask Ubuntu is currently trying to change policy to make 16.04 off topic here. ESM is free and not too hard to set up. I discus a bit about activating it at this link: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19510/is-ubuntu-14-04-off-topic-on-ask-ubuntu/19529#19529 You can vote to continue Ask Ubuntu support for ESM versions of Ubuntu here: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19543/policy-change-proposal-end-of-standard-support-for-esm-releases-is-effectivel

Answer (score 4):

You may be able to jog your memory with one or both commands below

```
ls -artl /var/cache/apt/archives
```

this will provide a list of the packages with the most recent ones listed near the end.

If an alphabetical approach appeals to you, then try

```
sudo apt list
```

When you find the package, then try

```
sudo apt remove pkgname
```

Another approach is to try finding the package name in your command history if you installed it with the terminal program

```
history | grep apt
```

will return all the commands you entered to manage packages.

If you used the dpkg command instead, then

```
history | grep dpkg
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is to list all the recent installs with the command

`grep " install " /var/log/dpkg.log`

and see if you could find the name of the package you installed.