# Can I make backup for the dpkg on linux mint and restore it on ubuntu?

Tags: backup

I have linux mint on my laptop and I want to replace it by Ubuntu, and i do not want to install all my packages again so can i make backup for my installed packages and restore it on fresh ubuntu?

Comment: No AFAIK it won't go !

Comment: I would not do this. What if any of the packages is Mint dependent? Redo your installation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command to see packages installed by the user and output it to a file:

```
comm -23 <(apt-mark showmanual | sort -u) <(gzip -dc /var/log/installer/initial-status.gz | sed -n 's/^Package: //p' | sort -u) > ~/packages
```

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/492343/668095)

---

Then on your new install after bringing over that generated file, you can install them like so:

```
sudo apt-get install $(cat packages)
```

### Why this approach is better

It allows `apt` to manage the dependencies for your platform like it is supposed to, and doesn't bring over system-installed libraries from Mint that Ubuntu will want to handle.