# Backup packages from 12.04 and install it on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, package-management, backup

hope that everyone is doing okay ,
I have a question , i want to know if it possible to install packages from 12.04 to 14.04 not all of them just a few (for exemple i want to transfer the packages that i installed on 12.04 two days ago on the 14.04 version) it is possible ? 
thank you for your help

Comment: See answer about `apt-clone` from the duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

Package names and dependencies shift over time, which makes this pretty unreliable to do. You are better off trying to get a list of the packages you want to have on the new system and then install the new versions of them on 14.04. That way you will have the ones supported by the OS and will get normal updates... Otherwise you will likely end up in "dependency hell."

See [Generating list of manually installed packages and querying individual packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2389/) for help getting the list of manually installed packages.

Comment: i'm trying to do that because the project that i'm working on , when i want to execute the main file i got this error ImportError : libboost_python-py27.so.1.46: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory

Comment: I'm guessing this is a package problem

Comment: Right so, what you probably need to do then is figure out which Python libraries you need to install on the new system. Python can be a little tricky because it also has it's own package management. So on your old system you need to figure out if you were using the built in `apt install some-package` or if you were using pip or other python package manager. If you were using the ubuntu (`apt`) one, the method I mentioned should get you on the right path. If however you were manually dropping Python libraries or using pip or other manager, you'll want to look into their docs respectively.

Comment: For Python boost libraries specifically, you might try `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev` -- as suggested on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578499/how-to-install-boost-on-ubuntu