# How do I list all packages that no package depends on?

Tags: apt, dependencies

First, an introduction. I just found a development server with all kinds of GUI packages installed. I'd like to know why. Therefore, I'd like to know which software has been installed that requires X.

I can answer this by answering two closely related questions:

- How can I list all installed packages that no other package depends on?
- How can I list all installed packages that no other package depends on, and that, directly or indirectly, depend on a given package?  (E.g., `x11-common`.)

For the first question, `apt-mark showmanual` is a useful approximation, but it may not be exactly right.

For the second question, [what I'm using now](https://www.win.tue.nl/~rp/dpkg-bin/apt-rdepends-ultimates) postprocesses the `apt-rdepends` output to list only results for which no dependencies are listed that are listed as results.

Is this correct? Is there an easier way? I notice the result contains quite a few packages that aren't marked as manually installed.

I need this on Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04, and 18.04.

Comment: Why not look at `/var/log/apt`? You should be able to see the install history there.

Comment: I don't want to pick logfiles apart by hand, I want those packages listed. Besides, by default, those logs don't last forever.

Comment: I'm not sure that "all installed packages that no other package depends on" is going to be a very useful list (it's going to include essential "top level" packages such as `login` for example) but I guess you could parse the output of `aptitude why` e.g. `dpkg --get-selections | while read pkg status; do [[ "$status" == "install" ]] && { aptitude why "$pkg" | grep '^Unable to find a reason'; }; done` . It will be painfully slow (but you might not care, for a one-off).

Comment: Just an idea: Automatically installed packages that no other packages depends on, are removed as unused packages by aptitude, provided the options `APT::Install-Recommends` and `APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant` are set to false. Or do you also want the manually installed packages that are not depended upon by any other package?

Comment: Basically, I want all software that was explicitly installed, rather than as a dependency of something else, even if that something else was installed later. I'm not sure just taking all packages resulting from `apt-mark showmanual` gives me that.

Comment: like this ? https://askubuntu.com/questions/2389/generating-list-of-manually-installed-packages-and-querying-individual-packages

Comment: Mmmm ... the original question is much the same, but the answer goes in a different direction, taking the `apt-mark show-manual` results and filtering out all initially installed packages. That's not what I want to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can for example list all installed packages with `dpkg-query` and then pipe the package names to `apt-cache` to see whether they have any reverse depedencies. Here's a one way to do it:

```
#!/bin/sh

dpkg-query --show --showformat='${Package}\t${Status}\n' | sed --quiet '
    /installed$/{
        s/^/apt-cache rdepends --installed /
        e
        s/\n/ /g                                                        
        /:$/{                                                               
            s/\s.*// 
            p                                   
        }    
    }               
'
```

if you want to do the reverse and list packages with at least one reverse dependency, just change `/:$/` to `/:$/!`

Comment: Very nice. The repeated calls to `apt-cache` make it slow though - I've amended it to `dpkg-query --show --showformat='${Package}\t${Status}\n' | tac | awk '/installed$/ {print $1}' | xargs apt-cache rdepends --installed | tac | awk '{ if (/^ /) ++deps; else if (!/:$/) { if (!deps) print; deps = 0 } }'
`

Comment: Great job, that's way faster than the version in my answer; I forgot that `apt-cache` can accept multiple arguments.

Comment: I learnt some `sed` along the way - I never knew it has an `e` command ...

Comment: As far as I know only the GNU version supports it.