# How can I list the all the packages installed and uninstall unwanted ones from that

Tags: apt, package-management

I'd like to output a list of all installed packages into a text file so that I can review it and bulk-install on another system. I even want to be able to uninstall unwanted ones. How would I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to list all installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages) and [Generating list of manually installed packages and querying individual packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2389/)

Comment: How will you know which packages are "unwanted"?  Parsing the dependency chains can be tedious. It's usually easier to build up what you want from a [Netinstall (minimal) image](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) than to tear down from a Desktop or Server Image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt, that this is a very good idea, but can do the following:

```
# Get packages from Host A
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall > outfile
# Install packages from Host A on Host B
sudo dpkg --set-selections < outfile
```