# Get software list of only user installed apps

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I am currently investigating the `http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/dpkg-query.1.html` `dpkg-query` feature but it produces a list of hundreds of system/cmd type installs. Is there a way to get a list of the software users have installed - similar to the "Ubuntu Software > Installed" screen?

Alternatively if I could exclude dependencies that might give a more accurate list. For example I have the following 4 rows returned, however really this should only be `apache2` server:

`ii  apache2        2.4.29-1ubun amd64        Apache HTTP Server`

`ii  apache2-bin    2.4.29-1ubun amd64        Apache HTTP Server (modules and o`

`ii  apache2-data   2.4.29-1ubun all          Apache HTTP Server (common files)`

`ii  apache2-utils  2.4.29-1ubun amd64        Apache HTTP Server (utility progr`

I guess I'm after a more human-friendly list and not sure which settings I need.

Unfortunately the suggested alternatives of `apt-mark showauto` from questions such as [Generating list of manually installed packages and querying individual packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2389) still return un-human friendly results such as:

`libwxbase3.0-0v5`
`libwxgtk3.0-0v5`
`libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5`

I have also looked at [How to list all installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages) as suggested.

`aptitude search '~i!~M'` gives me files including `x11-utils` `update-inetd` and `perl-modules-5.26`. None of these are applicable and this is also the case for `/var/lib/apt/extended_states`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating list of manually installed packages and querying individual packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2389/generating-list-of-manually-installed-packages-and-querying-individual-packages)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/880805/158442

Comment: Not really as I'm getting `dconf-cli, dconf-gsettings-backend, dconf-service` returned in my results yet I never installed those

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to list all installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages)

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have revised my question with the reasons.