# Unable to install anything using apt-get or update - error about GRUB configuration file and processing kernel image

Tags: boot, apt, grub2, kernel, dpkg

```
(Reading database ... 234944 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-5.8.0-55-generic (5.8.0-55.62~20.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-55-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Script `/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new' contains no commands and will do nothing
Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new file attached.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.8.0-55-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.8.0-55-generic package post-removal script subprocess r
eturned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.8.0-55-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.                                      
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: You've provided no OS & release, however many of the packages in your paste are rather out-of-date or from EOL releases.  What OS & release are you using?

Comment: @karel it seem not working i tried it same error

Comment: You have repositories not for Ubuntu 20.04 currently enabled and packages not for Ubuntu 20.04 currently installed. This is causing package management errors.

Comment: @karel you mean there is something worng here https://pastebin.com/XqEppWf3
this is my sources.list file

Comment: Your pastebin paste is OK, but your system has packages not for 20.04 currently installed which is causing the package management errors.

Comment: @karel but how can I find them

Comment: Use the rmadison tool which is provided by `sudo apt install devscripts` on each package in the output to identify packages with incompatible with 20.04 versions. Syntax: `rmadison linux-generic`

Comment: @karel it seems that i can not install the packages for the same error I really do not know what to do I have this problem for like three months, I am thinking of changing the distro but I want to make sure that my data won't be gone, is there a way to change the disto without losing the packages and programs that I have installed?

Comment: [How to list manually installed packages?](https://askubuntu.com/q/2389/) Save the list of manually installed packages and then reinstall them with a command of the form `sudo apt install package1 package2`

Comment: @karel I just have one thing in mind before doing this, if what you said is right that there is a package that is not compatible with my version of ubuntu then if I save the list of all the packages won't the same package get installed and I will get the same problem?

Comment: Don't try to reinstall any packages that have version numbers in their names. Most manually installed packages don't have version numbers in their names. If the package has a version number in its name you can use a command of the form `apt search package1` to find the correct version. That will get you a working system.

Comment: There is something that I do not understand installing from snap works but from apt, i get the error why this happens

Comment: Your package management issue is with apt packages only, not with any snap packages.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move problematic file out the way by

```
sudo mv /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new ~
sudo update-grub
```

and then resume package installation by

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Still getting the same Error

Comment: dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.8.0-55-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.8.0-55-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.8.0-55-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Please run `sudo update-grub` and retry. If error log is long - upload it to pastebin and share the link.

Comment: I got this 
```Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Script `/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new' contains no commands and will do nothing
Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new file attached.```  when running ` sudo update-grub`and the rest are the same error

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zzyr2TzB

Comment: Please also share the contents of `cat /etc/default/grub` and `ls /etc/grub.d/*` and `cat /etc/grub.d/*` .

Comment: https://pastebin.com/UiGkFqdX