# How do I check if a package comes preinstalled with Ubuntu or if I installed it myself?

Tags: apt

I'm writting instructions for someone else, and I want to know if I need to include a couple `apt install` commands in my snippet to make it completely copy/paste-able on a fresh Ubuntu installation.

How do I see if a given program was included with my Ubuntu installation or if I installed it myself later?

They're running the same Ubuntu version as me, so I don't need to know if the program only started being pre-installed in a certain Ubuntu version.

Comment: Check `/var/log/apt/history.log`

Comment: Or just check whether a representative file is there, for example the binary. `ls /usr/bin/something | wc -l` or something along those lines.

Comment: @StephenBoston I might've installed it months ago, will it still be there?

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck I'm not trying to write a script with dependency management. I don't want to touch other people's machines. Surely there's a command for checking what requested an installation?

Comment: Usually. You might find a gzipped file. The top of the file will show you the start date.

Comment: Unzip all the gzipped files and run `grep -E 'Requested|Command' history.log -- or whatever file name` (The oldest file will have the highest version number.)  You can see those commands that specify `install` rather than 'upgrade' or whatever. Some entries are rather long (upgrades for example) but otherwise it is an easy parse.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix it's even more of a duplicate of the question linked in that question [Is it possible to tell what packages I've installed that aren't in the vanilla install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365/is-it-possible-to-tell-what-packages-ive-installed-that-arent-in-the-vanilla-i)

Comment: @Boris I changed the word "program" in the Title to "package" - I guess that is really what you are asking. Every program (that was installed through apt/aptitude/Software center) is part of a package but a package can contain multiple programs. Feel free to revert my edit if that was not what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to determine if a package is installed by the Ubuntu Desktop Installer is to check if it's included in the `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage. That's the metapackage that defines what the installer will install:

You can see the list of immediate dependencies using the command: `apt depends ubuntu-desktop`.

But what if your package is not listed among the immediate dependencies? You can easily find out by testing the package with apt.

For example, let's simulate the removal of `nautilus` (the Gnome file manager). We will, of course, use the `--simulate` flag; there is no need to destroy our system to answer this simple question. You can see below that removing `nautilus` also results in the removal of `ubuntu-desktop`. This is conclusive proof that `nautilus` is installed by the Desktop Ubuntu installer:

```
$ apt remove nautilus --simulate
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
      [...]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons nautilus nautilus-share ubuntu-desktop
  ubuntu-desktop-minimal
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 5 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Remv ubuntu-desktop [1.440]
Remv ubuntu-desktop-minimal [1.440]
Remv gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons [19.10.2-1]
Remv nautilus-share [0.7.3-2ubuntu3]
Remv nautilus [1:3.34.1-1ubuntu1]
```

Let's expand on that example in two ways. Let's move down the dependency tree and try to remove a sub-dependency (`nautilus-data`). We do this by changing from `remove` to `autoremove`. Also, let's use `grep` to reduce the output. You can see below that this is an effective way to test any (sub-)dependency of `ubuntu-desktop` *anywhere* in the chain of dependencies. The `nautilus-data` package is installed by the Ubuntu Desktop Installer:

```
$ apt autoremove nautilus-data --simulate | grep ubuntu-desktop
  session-shortcuts tree ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal
Remv ubuntu-desktop [1.440]
Remv ubuntu-desktop-minimal [1.440]
```

Let's look at the case with the opposite result. `chrome` is NOT a dependency of `ubuntu-desktop`. It was installed sometime later. Removing it WON'T remove `ubuntu-desktop`:

```
$ apt autoremove chrome --simulate | grep ubuntu-desktop
(No output)
```

Comment: Is not shotwell in the install programs of the Ubuntu installer.  I think the OP is asking if he could tell difference from the regular programs that are installed with installation and programs someone installs after, like chrome.

Comment: @crip659 thanks for catching what would indeed confuse. Take a look now and see if it's clearer.

Comment: Unfortunately he would get no output also, if he used firefox instead of chrome.  Firefox is one of the programs installed with Ubuntu.

Comment: @crip659. Another good catch. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

The apt-mark showmanual ... is close to what you want, but it lists things like updates of preinstalled things too.  Put the below command string into a file, and run it as a script:

```
comm -23 <(apt-mark showmanual | sort -u) <(gzip -dc /var/log/installer/initial-status.gz | sed -n 's/^Package: //p' | sort -u)
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is any script or program that does what you want.  About the only way to tell is to run the Ubuntu live USB and see if there are any programs not on it.  A few programs do not get installed, like gparted, it is on 'live' but not on installed version.  Have seen a few questions like this.

Comment: Is there a website or something that keeps track of this? Doesn't need to be a command.

Comment: Right now I usually just google "is X installed on Ubuntu". If that doesn't work I start up a $5 instance on DigitalOcean to check, but there must be a better way.

Comment: Can try using synaptic package manager and use the installed(manual) section.  That will probably be as close as possible.  Some stuff will be from updates, but think you can see those yourself, and weed out what you installed.